# Running bash script with login session from batch file doesn't execute .bashrc

Tags: bash, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a batch file that is an entry point for starting a python program in wsl (since it has to use .so shared library file).

**In short**

The problem is that the line `bash.exe --login ./start_program.sh` doesn't call the .bashrc file.

**In more detail**:

I use WSL2 and Ubuntu18.04 from the windows store.

As I am using conda as a python environment and added the line "export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0" to the .bashrc file to let python show some data, I need the the .bashrc file to be executed before starting the python program.

I changed the ~/.profile script to contain the lines

```
if [-f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    echo $pwd
    echo $HOME
    . "$HOME/.bashr"
fi
```

When I start wsl manually, the .bashrc file is executed and everything is fine and when I run the script start_program.sh the program starts.
The output at at the start of wsl was as expected:

```
<empty line>
/home/dries
```

The problems start when I try to run it from a batch file. When I try either of the two

```
wsl.exe ./start_program.sh
bash.exe ./start_program.sh
```

It doesn't call the .profile file and it fails.
When the .bat file contains

```
bash.exe --login ./start_program.sh
```

It executes the ~/.profile script, but this doesn't call the .bashrc script. The output of the .profile file is the same (empty line and /home/dries), but the .bashrc file is not called.

I suspect that it has something to do with looking for the files in windows-style or in Unix-style, but I'm not sure.

I hope someone can help me with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I was very happy to eventually stumble across this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439151/passing-command-to-bash-from-cmd-exe-wsl-not-working

The -i option worked for me. Now I use

```
bash.exe -c -i ./start_program.sh
```